# want to get total count of records in a table using COUNT(*) in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query which will return all the details from table along with i need max_row count i.e total no of rows in a table using COUNT(*) in a single select query without using cross join.
Note: MySQL version is earlier version  of 8

Query :

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY column name DESC LIMIT 0,10;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total count of a table is simple, when you want to add it to every row.

```
SELECT 
     *
     ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename  ) count1 
FROM tablename 
ORDER BY column name 
DESC LIMIT 0,10;,
```